# Understanding assert_equal in Test::Unit with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, assert

I have the following code:

```
test "unique title" do
    product = Product.new(title:       products(:ruby).title,
                          description: 'yyy',
                          price:       1,
                          image_url:   "fred.gif")

    assert !product.save
    puts product.errors[:title].join('; ')
    assert_equal "has already been taken", product.errors[:title].join('; ')
  end
```

The test passes. But I fail to understand why the assert_equal doesn't trigger an error.

Because "has already been taken" is not equal to: `ProductTest#test_unique_titlehas already been taken`

Which is the output of the puts statement.

Why does this test pass?

Comment: I think you are getting confused because there is somehow no new line in your output. `ProductTest#test_unique_title` describes the test method you are running and `has already been taken` is the result of your `puts` so the test should pass.

Comment: I understand, you should have made it an answer so I can award you the reputation :). I guess the test framework automatically shows the method that's being executed when any output is provided..

Comment: Added it as an answer so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting confused because there is somehow no new line in your output.  ProductTest#test_unique_title describes the test method you are running and has already been taken is the result of your puts so the test should pass

Answer (score 1):

Completely out of your question. But you don't have to save the record to check if its valid. You can call valid? method to have the errors populated.

```
test "unique title" do
    product = Product.new(title:       products(:ruby).title,
                          description: 'yyy',
                          price:       1,
                          image_url:   "fred.gif")

    assert !product.valid?
    assert_equal "has already been taken", product.errors[:title].join('; ')
end
```